# Error: Voice call using twilo in php code

Tags: php, twilio

I using twilio for call system, but my error:

> Error: Account not authorized to call +84983xxxxxx. Perhaps you need
>   to enable some international permissions:
>   https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international

I checked in Vietnam (+84) via https://www.twilio.com/user/account/settings/international but still encounter the same error

My php code:

```
<?php
require 'twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php';
function call_notify($number) {

// Twilio REST API version
$version = "2010-04-01";

// Set our Account SID and AuthToken
$sid = 'AC34962eb3f445dfa40893e64bb8xxxxxx';
$token = '9b0667c68299cf484228344d67xxxxxx';

// A phone number you have previously validated with Twilio
$phonenumber = '+155920xxxxx';

// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version);


try {
      // Initiate a new outbound call
      $call = $client->account->calls->create(
      $phonenumber, // The number of the phone initiating the call
      $number, // The number of the phone receiving call
      'http://103.255.238.29/notify.xml' // The URL Twilio will request when the call is answered
        );
    echo 'Started call: ' . $call->sid;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
   }

}

call_notify("+84983xxxxxx");
```

Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I clicked on the URL to the international settings but was redirected to the Messaging international settings.

Can you go to the Voice international settings here https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions and ensure you have Vietnam checked on that page too.

I'll feedback that the error is pointing to the wrong page.

Let me know if that helps!